# Unable to confirm Facebook app ads install tracking

Tags: facebook, mobile, tracking, ads

Per Facebook's documentation on Section 3 of Get started measuring app installs on page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/

I have added these two lines in my code:

[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:YOUR_APP_ID];
[FBAppEvents activateApp];

I am UNABLE to see any confirmation of installs as mentioned in app summary page

Confirm that installs are being tracked You can confirm that the volume of installs is being correctly reported in the Insights section for your app in the App Dashboard. In addition, in the App Summary Page, there is a time stamp 'Last Mobile Install Reported" for iOS and Android so that you can confirm that an install is being reported (see image below - ).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGP24.png

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Did you follow all of the instructions exactly? I've yet to see a problem with this which wasn't due to a mistake with configuring the SDK or calling the publishInstall (older SDK) or activateApp method in the correct place(s)

Comment: Your comment would be more helpful if you gave examples of where people made mistakes.  The FB documents are rather simple to follow - yet we are experiencing the same problem.  Nothing is registering.  It is unclear if testing can be done on a simulator - or if we need to try "fresh" devices - or how to make a device "fresh" if it has been registered as an install previously.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bite late but it can be useful to others.

To test the mobile ads install and see the "Last Mobile Install Reported" in the app dashboard.

You have to make sure that you have installed the facebook app and beeing logged-in from your **DEVICE**.

you need to add these two lines in your app delegate in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, as you did:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:FACEBOOK_APP_ID];

    [FBAppEvents activateApp];
}
```